# Can't overload == for template in class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

This code:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    operator ==(const T &a, const T &b);
}
```

cause error:

```
bool Tree<T>::operator==(const T&, const T&)’ must take exactly one argument
```

Comment: I'd like to overload == for Template, not for class

Comment: This is a class template, what do you mean? How do you plan on using it? Show us the complete example.

Comment: please always use the language tag

Comment: template is nothing. It's a concept. It's not a type declaration, it doesn't generate code.  When it is instantiated, it instructs compiler to create type declaration for objects that use instantiation. That's why C++ sometimes called concretization-oriented language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: @MarekR since when we can make operators static?

Comment: Did any of these answers help you? Talk to us.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two ways.

```
friend bool operator== (MyClass const & lhs, MyClass const & rhs); 

bool MyClass::operator== (MyClass const & rhs) const;
```

You have sort of combined them now. Use one of the above.

Either a friend function outside the class, or (as suggested by rafix07) remove the other object from the member function.

Also you might want to read this:
[What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 0):

Member operators, like any other member function, have one operand hidden. It's `*this` object and they access left-hand operator through `this` pointer. For other member functions it meant to be left-hand operand of operators `->` or `.` (dot).

That leads to next difference between member operator and stand-alone operator: stand-alone operator can be used with left-hand operand that can be converted to the specified type. That's not possible when using a member. Either behavior might be desirable depending on semantics.

E.g. you want use operator == to check if two instances of same type are equal:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    T  data;
public:  // note: this is important, if operator 
         // is not public, only this class can do comparison.
    bool operator ==(const A &b) {
        // this would invoke operator == for T class 
        return  this->data == b.data; 
    }
    // compare data with T object
    bool operator ==(const T &b) {
        return  this->data == b; 
    }
};
```

For template class standalone operators are problematic. They have to be templates and to be declared in way they can be used for that template. It's rarely done outside of libraries.